# How can I continue having two fingers on the trackpad?

Tags: multi-touch, trackpad, macbook-pro

I'm quite new to ubuntu (with GUI) - just got over from OS X.

I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my MacBook Pro 9.2, and I have the habit of leaving one finger at the bottom of the trackpad ready to click while I am using another finger to move the cursor around. This is NOT possible with my current settings. The moment I have two fingers on the trackpad, either the mouse pointer stops moving or the window starts scrolling.

Is there anyone who know how I can get it to accept my habit, or am I just going to live with it?

Comment: This is a problem with trackpads without "real" buttons, it confuses the two finger scrolling.

Comment: I have the same problem in Ubuntu 18.04 with a non-MAC laptop. Does anyone know any fix? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This article:

[How to Get MacBook-Style Finger Gestures on Ubuntu Linux](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/43097/how-to-get-macbook-style-finger-gestures-on-ubuntu-linux/)

... may not give you exactly what you want, but it should help make the transition a little bit nicer. I do not have this installed myself so I cannot test for the specific scenario you outlined. If it does work please report back here.